# Burnside lemma applied to regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem with understanding how to find out what numbers I have to use in this tricky formula from wikipedia when it comes to convex regular polygon. What I have? Well...
There's n-th vertices polygon like [here](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/37400/37412/5gon_05-05_37412_lg.gif) and I have 2-colors. I have to colouring all triangles using those colours. And then I have to tell how many different polygons out there, but:

- Rotation is indistinguishable
- If you took a sheet of paper, draw it and look from opposite side of it (I guess it's hidden way to say: symmetric via any side) is indistinguishable

Could you explain me step by step how to approach such problems? Does it matter it's even or odd number of vertices in such problems?

Comment: I wrote [a tutorial about this](http://blog.plover.com/math/polya-burnside.html), and the first example is how to count the number of ways of coloring the triangles of a 4-gon in just the way you want. The emphasis is on coloring the 4-gon with $n$ colors, instead of on coloring an $n$-gon with 2 colors, but if you work through the examples it should be clear how to do your problem instead.

Comment: I will try to work it out. If I still have a question I will surely ask. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your tutorial completely but if it's up to rotations and symmetric you have error in it. It's just up to rotations. But thanks anyway I finally solve my problem, thanks to below information about dihedral group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the three main steps for these types of problems:

1. identify the symmetry group $G$
2. for every $g\in G$, count the number of colorings fixed by $g$ (denote it as ${\rm fix}(g)$, say)

   - to expedite the above, try to see ahead of time when two elements $g,h$ will fix the same number of colorings, so that you don't have to count more than you need to
3. find the average of all of the ${\rm fix}(g)$'s

If you wish, you can update your question with your progress on these items as you see fit, or comment below with any requests for clarification/elaboration.

Comment: I've read it. Doesn't help in my case, I not able to identify symmetry groups when it comes to n-th vertices. Any pattern?

Comment: @Kostek: The problem mentions two group actions, *rotations* and flipping the paper over (*reflections*). Which group is the symmetry group of the $n$-gon comprised of rotations and reflections? It is called the [*dihedral group*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group).

Comment: The symmetry group for a regular $n$-gon has $n$ rotations of 0, $1/n$ of a full turn, $2/n$ of a full turn, and so on, plus, if you are counting reflections, a reflection across $n$ different midlines through the center of the $n$-gon.

Comment: @anon Thanks, very useful information - dihedral group. I solve my problem according to this.